Настройка Unity 5.6.3f1 под разработку на Android
Ситуация следующая: Есть Unity 5.6.3f1 на которой я работаю и хотел бы продолжить на ней работать, так как я к ней привык и в ней есть все, что мне необходимо и нет ничего лишнего, но проблема в том, что я не могу собрать apk-файл.
С jdk проблем не возникает, а вот с sdk вылетают ошибки:
(Error:C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools is not a directory. calculated from system property com.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir)
Путь jdk: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11
Путь sdk: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
Данную операцию я пытался проделать и с версией 2022.3.37f1, но результат примерно такой же.
Обе версии Unity я устанавливал через установщик и у меня не было выбора автоматической настройки компонентов, так как через Unity Hub у меня, почему то происходит только скачивание, а процесс установки (я так полагаю) длится вечность и не доходит до завершения.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Купи на Avito самый дешёвый компьютер с x64 процем и нормально пользуйся последней версией Unity3D, где кстате все необходимые sdk давно уже устанавливаются сами.

Я же говорю - меня устраивает целиком и полностью та версия, которая у меня есть и я не хотел бы ее менять. И еще на счет новой версии - я установил 2022.3.37f1 и на ней нет ничего этого, так как устанавливал я ее через установщик, а не клиент. А через клиент не могу, так как у меня он только скачивает, а установка не доходит до своего логического завершения. Плюс, в этой последней версии просто очень много всего ненужного мне.
